# Laravel error uploading image using $file->move()

Tags: laravel, laravel-filesystem

My uploading function:

```
public function uploadImage($file, $path) {
    $filename = Str::random(6) . '_' . time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $uploads_folder = public_path() . $path;
    if (!file_exists($uploads_folder)) {
        mkdir($uploads_folder, 0777, true);
    }
    $image = $path . "/" . $filename;

    $file->move($uploads_folder, $filename);
    return $image;
}
```

It worked fine for the past weeks but now this exception appeared:: `Unsupported operand types`
the return statement didn't apply but the file is saved on the folder correctly.

Comment: BTW: setting ``$uploads_folder`` to ``0777`` permission is TOTALLY not recommended due to security concerns!

Comment: IF the file is saved correctly then how can you save that ``$file->move()`` is not working! Kindly, state clearly! And ``Unsupported operand types`` is shown for which line of code exactly?

Comment: Although this is Laravel, you have a lot of plain PHP... Have you tried using the Storage class? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue with the `$path` variable that you're using to construct the image and the unsupported operand types is probably because the $path is not outputting a String.

To make sure that it is really a string you can use the `strval` around the path like so:

```
$image = strval($path) . "/" . $filename;
```